# Positioning punctuation to the bottom right of an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, boxes, baseline

I'm writing a paper with tikz-based equations that look like this:

[image]

I like to have punctuation after equations, but I think it would look better and be less confusing if the punctuation was at the bottom-right of the equation, instead of aligned with the baseline. Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Note that the equals sign needs to remain vertically centred - I only want to affect the positioning of the full stop or comma at the end of the equation.

I'd prefer to avoid discussing the stylistic choices involved. (It's kind of an interesting topic, but not really suited to Stack Exchange as a venue.)

Here's an mwe. Note that I set the baseline of the tikz figure to near the centre, so that the equals sign is centred correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dummybox}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.45ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\draw (0,0) node[
    fill=white,
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum height=0.5in,
    minimum width=1in] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \dummybox
  \quad = \quad
  \dummybox
\quad.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried putting the whole equation (except for the full stop) inside an `\mbox`, but that changed the spacing around the equals sign, so I guess that isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: If I understand your use case correctly, neither approach to placing the sentence-ending punctuation mark is going to be completely satisfactory. I'm guessing that your use case arises in a construct such as "..., as may be seen in the following equation: `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`". I think it would be much more elegant to avoid any risk of this problem cropping up in the first place, by rephrasing the construct as "... The following equation establishes this result. `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`" (note the period (aka "full stop") at the end of the sentence).

Comment: @Mico thanks, I think it's good advice in general, but I tend to write in a fairly conversational style with a lot of equations. Often I put equations in the middle of a sentence, followed by a comma rather than a full stop. One could always write to avoid that sort of thing, but I'm fairly comfortable with this style and I'd prefer to keep using it.

Comment: Incidentally, the sample code you posted does not properly establish a baseline. As a result, the `.` symbol ends up being placed a bit too high. Try replacing `\dummybox.` with `\vcenter{\hbox{\dummybox}}.` to see what I mean.

Comment: Does` [baseline={([yshift=1ex]current bounding box.south)}]` suit your needs?

Comment: @NBur no, because I only want to affect the punctuation at the end of the equation - the equals sign needs to stay where it is. (I've edited to make that clearer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I find putting the period in line with the equation number to be more apparent than at the bottom.  Also, I make every effort to **not** put punctuation in equations, but sometimes it is unavoidable.

That being said, you can use a subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dummybox}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.45ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\draw (0,0) node[
    fill=white,
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum height=0.5in,
    minimum width=1in] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left.
  \dummybox
  \quad = \quad
  \dummybox
  \quad\right._{\displaystyle .}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This puts the punctuation in a suitable position, but also in a smaller font. (Easily fixed with `\displaystyle`.)

Comment: @Nathaniel - Thanks.  I couldn't tell the difference at first glance.

Comment: I'm using this and it seems to work quite well. I put in a `\raisebox` as well, so that the punctuation isn't quite at the bottom of the bounding box, but close to it. I'm actually sort of tempted to take Rmano's advice and just embed the punctuation in the tikz figure, because then I could position it manually so that the lowest 'wire' appears to be the baseline - but I have a lot of these equations and there's definitely a time trade-off involved, so I'm going with this solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can always put the dot in the tikzpicture, making it sticks out without changing the bounding box with `overlay`:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dummybox}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.45ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\draw (0,0) node[
    fill=white,
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum height=0.5in,
    minimum width=1in] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\dummyboxwithfullstop}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.45ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\draw (0,0) node[
    fill=white,
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum height=0.5in,
    minimum width=1in] {};
    \path[overlay] (current bounding box.south east) node{\qquad .};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \dummybox
  \quad = \quad
  \dummyboxwithfullstop
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```